# Trying connect by SSH and get "access denied" by localtunnel

Tags: ssh, tunnel

Hey I installed localtunnel - http://progrium.com/localtunnel/ and I tried connect from my laptop using putty(I even unckecked attempt gssapi authentication) and I receive

```
login as: hsf
hsf@4i67.localtunnel.com's password:
Access denied
hsf@4i67.localtunnel.com's password:
```

Comment: Try logging as root user instead of hsf and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Evandro Silva I tried and problem is the same.

Comment: In my work, usually, I just install `ssh` and then use putty as `sudo`. I never really used localtunnel. :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to authenticate with the SSH private key that corresponds to the public key that you used to set up your tunnel. The latter is explained in the instructions on [1], while the reasons for using public keys are explained in [2]. However I cannot find there which username to use along with your SSH key. To me [2] sounds like they are using only one user whose authorized_keys file contains all public keys. If so, it is unlikely that you can use e.g. your subdomain as the username. I tried looking it up for you (can probably be done with `ps -o args -C ssh` while localtunnel is running) but didn't get localtunnel to work on my machine quickly.

[1] http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

[2] http://www.twilio.com/engineering/2011/06/06/making-a-local-web-server-public-with-localtunnel